# Regular expression for email

Tags: regex

Hei , 
I have written following regular expression for validating email its working but its not validating when i write test@test...test.com . it should give error on this email id because its not valid . Can anybody tell what to wrong in the following regulat expression

Regex for email.

@"^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+).([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+$

It should validate all following

1. mkyong@yahoo.com, mkyong-100@yahoo.com, mkyong.100@yahoo.com
2. mkyong111@mkyong.com, mkyong-100@mkyong.net, mkyong.100@mkyong.com.au
3. mkyong@1.com, mkyong@gmail.com.com
4. mkyong+100@gmail.com, mkyong-100@yahoo-test.com

Comment: just look at links on the right - section **Related**

Comment: @Artur that's a very valid point - One should also look into **Related** section of SO

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions on email addresses is dealt with in details, here:

[REGEX - Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)